# JavaScript scrollTop function

Tags: javascript, html

I have been using JavaScript `scrollTop` function to scroll the div to top by 5 px. but its not working.
I am using:

```
scdiv.scrollTop = "5px";
```

The problem is it scrolls the div to top instead of moving to 5 px. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add more of your code to see if the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Also, can you post an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop

Comment: Do you want the *page* to scroll down by `5px`?

Comment: no the div, my div id is scdiv

Comment: I want the div "scdiv" scroll by 5 px on btn click

Answer (score 1):

scrollTop is a property, its value is an int.

```
div.scrollTop += 5;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourButtonId").on('click',function(){

var scDiv = $("#scdiv");

var top = scDiv.css('top');

top = parseInt(top);

scDiv.css('top',(top-5)+"px");

//To make it visually scrollable


  scDiv.animate({
    top: top
  },500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` accepts integer numbers, it doesn't understand CSS values like `px`, so you would use something like this: `element.scrollTop += 5;`

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pMafC/.

You can click a button to make the `div` scroll.

See [scrollTop - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop).